# I want to take off the scroll view on my GUI in xCode

Tags: xcode, macos, scrollview

I put in a scroll view on my main storyboard. Now I want to take it out because I want to add some more thing on to it but when I delete the UIScrollView it deletes all of my labels and buttons that were enabled in the scroll along with it.

I have also tried extending it but then the scroll feature is disabled.

Comment: So the labels and buttons are in a clip view that is part of the scrollview and that's why they are removed with the scroll view. You will have to put the labels and buttons back after you remove the scroll view.

Comment: So there is no way to detach these button from the clip view?

Comment: You can "detach" them by moving them out of the scrollview